# New home foundation

Tags: foundation

I have a question. I am thinking of buying a newly constructed home. I was at the site the day before they started putting up the cinderblocks for the slab foundation. I was sinking past my ankles in mud in areas the the cinderblocks was being put. The old house that was there had a basement and had issues where sump pumps had to be put in. We have been having issues with lots of rain for last 3 months. I contacted the builder and was told not to worry because had added sand to the soil.

Comment: Don’t stop your questions with the builder.  Especially if that was the answer you received.  Find out what the drainage plan is.  Drainage is extremely important and encompasses much more than adding sand to some soil.

Comment: If it was me, I wouldn't have a warm fuzzy feeling about that builder.  Even if everything has been inspected and approved as described in Jack's answer, then the builder didn't give you a straight answer.  Personally, I wouldn't trust dealing with him or buying something he's built.

Answer (score 2):

There are only a few states that don't require inspections, but if you are in a state that does require inspections which almost all states do, the ground should have been tested before the concrete was poured. To my knowledge, water is NEVER to be present in a footing while being poured, and a footing is NEVER to be filled in with ANYTHING unless a soils engineer approves it, which will be in writing. No matter what was done, there should be something in writing before the concrete was poured to verify the solidity of the ground under the concrete. There could be mud everyplace else, but if the ground is solid under the footing which the cinder block rest on, it is cool...